# Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit - unable to search/filter by date/time

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am trying to use PowerShell and the **Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit** cmdlet to monitor certain events, such as the following:

```
Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -Filter "LoggedByService eq 'PIM'" | Select -First 1 | FL

ActivityDateTime     : 17/06/2022 08:54:10
ActivityDisplayName  : Remove member from role (PIM activation expired)
AdditionalDetails    : {RoleDefinitionOriginId, RoleDefinitionOriginType, TemplateId, Metadata}
Category             : RoleManagement
CorrelationId        : f998b539-74cc-4e27-9c33-800ddda42018
Id                   : PIM_f998b539-74cc-4e27-9c33-800ddda42018_0CH8K_7752548
InitiatedBy          : Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Models.MicrosoftGraphAuditActivityInitiator
LoggedByService      : PIM
OperationType        : RemoveActivatedRole
Result               : success
ResultReason         :
TargetResources      : {c4e39ds9-1100-34d3-8c65-fb160da0071f, 2ZgtrAAR00aMZfsWDaAHH-5TcmutkjtCiF12YUIjO4s-1, f7ddc610-e91d-4…}
AdditionalProperties : {}
```

However, I need to retrieve certain log entries that happened in the last *x* hours, but no matter how I try to filter on **ActivityDateTime**, I always get the following error (I've tried all possible combinations and formats!):
`Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit_List1: Invalid filter clause`

If ActivityDateTime is not supported as a filter parameter, how can we search log entries after a certain date or within a certain timeframe? Thank you!

Best regards,
Nuno

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryaudit-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#optional-query-parameters) `activityDateTime` attribute supports `eq`, `ge`, `le` operators

The query should look like this

```
GET /auditLogs/directoryAudits?&$filter=activityDateTime le 2022-06-15
GET /auditLogs/directoryAudits?&$filter=activityDateTime ge 2022-06-15
```

PowerShell

```
Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -Filter "activityDateTime+le+2022-06-15"
Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -Filter "activityDateTime+ge+2022-06-15"
```

Including time

```
GET /auditLogs/directoryAudits?&$filter=activityDateTime le 2022-06-15T21:20:02.7215374Z
GET /auditLogs/directoryAudits?&$filter=activityDateTime ge 2022-06-15T00:00:00.0000000Z
```

PowerShell

```
Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -Filter "activityDateTime+le+2022-06-15T21:20:02.7215374Z"
Get-MgAuditLogDirectoryAudit -Filter "activityDateTime+ge+2022-06-15T00:00:00.0000000Z"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @user2250152!

This is stupid... First, I was specifying the date with a "/" separator (just like with the values returned), but it has to be "-"...
Second, I was specifying the date as "dd/MM/yyyy" (just like with the values returned), but it has to be "yyyy-MM-dd".
Third, I was placing the date inside 'single quotes' (just like 99% of all filtering examples), but it can't have ''...